# Java string loop pattern

Tags: java, string

I'm going through some introductory exercises and I can not understand how to get java to output a string of five letters in the particular pattern shown below.
[image: said pattern]

Initially I thought it followed the tribonacci sequence for number of characters per line. Without just printing the line, I can not figure out how to have java logically replicate the pattern. They seem to copy each other, but don't really follow a pattern.

Comment: what is your input? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So I have worked with the classic pyramid builds but they go in a linear fashion, while this doesn't. Some initial attempts have been with stating each letter as a string, than adding each one to the previous, but that only increases by one as well.

Comment: This would be an ideal problem to solve using recursion (have a look at "recursive functions")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings are palindrome and getting its end from the last string, for example; line 2 has "ABA" string, so line 3 will copy "ABA" at its end and will insert character C in the middle, so the final string will be "ABACABA"

```
String LastPattern="";
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println( LastPattern + (char)(65+i) +LastPattern);
            LastPattern=LastPattern + (char)(65+i) +LastPattern;
        }
```

Comment: Hint. just dropping code without any explanations: doesnt make a good answer!

Comment: That's fantastic, but yeah if you could have some explanation of the logic behind why/how it's done that way that would be fantastic. I'd be happy to mark it as an answer then.

Comment: The strings are palindrome and copying getting its end from the last string, for example; line 2 has "ABA" string, so line 3 will copy "ABA" at its end and will insert character C in the middle, so the final string will be "ABACABA".

Comment: @fatmi Update your answer with this comment

Comment: does this explanation help now?

Comment: Yes it does. Once you update the answer I'll mark it as accepted. I will research more into what you used in the answer to avoid asking as many questions like this in the future.

Comment: Two things, you should improve. First, name the variable according to the code conventions, i.e. starting with a lower case letter. Second, you have code duplication. You are performing `LastPattern + (char)(65+i) +LastPattern` twice per iteration, without any reason. You can do the `lastPattern=…` assignment first, followed by a simple `System.out.println(lastPattern);`.

Comment: @Holger, you are right but I was in hurry, so I didn't have much time to check for these things. But. in future I will definately take care of these things. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this gets you going:

Something

Something New Something

Something New Something **Newer** Something New Something

The pattern is there, right in front of you.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'm just legitimately too new at this to be able to understand it. If this is a wasted post I'll delete it.

Comment: I suppose. I just wish I could better articulate my question so that it's not a waste of space on here but I don't know enough to properly ask in this language.

Comment: You're creating palindromes around an increasing character if you wanted to be more clear on what you're doing @bonzo.